# run thread 24/7 in asp web application

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I'm trying to realize a web application with asp.net mvc in which I must receive email 24/7 and do some treatment and notify the specific user .My question is how can I run a thread all time even if the user is not logged.

for the email reception I use `S22.Imap`:

```
AutoResetEvent ReconnectEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
ImapClient Client;

while (true)
{
    Client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, "login", "password", AuthMethod.Login, true);
    ReconnectEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: what do you do when an email is received?  Could this be better served by a service running alongside the website with some form of shared storage (db etc)?

Comment: Generally it's better to offload this kind of constant work into a separate service (a different program). If you want it to run within the context of the web applicaiton there's a number of pitfalls, and you'll find [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) very useful.

Comment: i already think about that, but how can i build a notification system in that case ?

Comment: Well if the user isn't on the site, how could you notify them via the site anyways? So you'll need some sort of persistent storage (like a database or message queue) to store notifications until the user logs in. Once they log in, you can show them.

Comment: yes i know, but when the user is logged ?

Comment: i store notification in database no matter what the user is there or not but i need to send notification when he/she is logged

Comment: When they access the site you can read from the storage to see if any notifications are awaiting. If so, display them to user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118033/discussion-between-boughti-and-mason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and the most efficient way of doing this will be by creating a separate service rather than keeping it within the asp.net app.

if you still wants to use it inside the app then explore the package called `WEBBACKGROUNDER` to run the task in the background.

hope this helps.